# Process string in Pandas Dataframe rows to comma-delimitered chars

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, with data in each row as such.

```
MKEYGEDLK
```

How can I process the sequence strings in each row, such that the format will be as such?

```
[M, K, E, Y, G, E, D, L, K]
```

I tried

```
get_seq_str = ','.join(test_df.loc[0]['seq_1'])
arr.append(get_seq_str)
```

However, when I append it to the dataframe, there is a single quotation mark at the start and end of each string, which I do not want.

```
['M, K, E, Y, G, E, D, L, K']
```

How can I strip the single quotation marks?

Comment: What is `print (test_df['seq_1'].head().tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `apply` `list` to string value

```py
df['col_list'] = df['col'].apply(list)
```

```
print(df)

         col                     col_list
0  MKEYGEDLK  [M, K, E, Y, G, E, D, L, K]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
get_seq_str = [*test_df.loc[0]['seq_1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['new'] = df['seq_1'].str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]')
```

Example:

```
         seq_1                          new
0    MKEYGEDLK  [M, K, E, Y, G, E, D, L, K]
1  ?MKEY GEDLK  [M, K, E, Y, G, E, D, L, K]
```